# VS2010 Debugger: The name 'VARIABLE_NAME' does not exist in the current context

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

Debugging an iterator method in VS2010 SP1 (with DEBUG settings... no compiler optimization), one of my variables, *operand*, "does not exist in the current context" according to Quick Watch in the Immediate Window (I also do not get a popup if I mouse over the variable).

The variable is in scope.

Thoughts on what might be causing tis or how to avoid it?

```
private IEnumerable<Answer> CreateVirtualFormulaAnswers(Question question, List<Answer> answers)
{
    string[] formulaParts = question.Formula.Split(FORMULA_SPLIT, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string formula = formulaParts[0].Trim();
    if (formulaParts.Length != 2) throw new Exception("Formula format is incorrect: " + question.Formula);

    // At this point:
    //    formulaParts.Length = 2
    //    formulaParts has a non-null string at each index
    //    Mouse over of "op" in VS2010 debugger does not show any popup
    //    Quick watch and immediate window both state: "The name 'operand' does not exist in the current context"
    string operand = formulaParts[1].Trim();

    string answerText = (from a in answers where a.QuestionCode == op select a.Text).SingleOrDefault();

    if (answerText != null)
    {
        yield return new Answer()
        {
            /* Initialization code here based on formula */
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it appear as in scope when you move to the next instruction? AFAIK you have to pass declaration for it to appear as "in scope".

Comment: @Tudor: Yes, the problem persists after passing the declaration.

Comment: Hmm, I can reproduce the problem in my own VS 2010. It must be a "feature". :)

Comment: @Tudor: I guess you're right.  I added additional findings as an answer.  Hopefully it will help someone else avoid head scratching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be, as Tudor suggests, a limitation of VS 2010 SP1.

I found that *operand* doesn't become visible to the debugger until it is actually used by code, not just past the point of assignment.

Specifically:

```
Debug.WriteLine(operand);
```

printed correctly to the console.

Also, once *operand* was evaluated by the *where* clause of the Linq statement, Quick Watch and the Immediate Window suddenly learned about it.

Comment: I tried this answer, but I'm still expierencing the same problem.